# Long integer division in awk

Tags: shell, awk

I want to strip last digit of a field and then perform some operation on the resulting number, for which I run this awk command:

```
awk '{if($8 == 346586 && (int($1/10))%10 == 0) {print int($1/10), $1}}' input_data
```

since $1 is long I get results of this kind:

> 2.02152e+17 2021523922099868685

Any clues how I can resolve this?

Comment: It must have to do with `printf` format. Can you show how `input_data` is?

Comment: Take a look at this [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arbitrary-Precision-Integers) explaining how to work with arbitrary precision integers in `awk.`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -M '$8 == 346586 && int($1/10))%10 == 0 {print int($1/10), $1}' input_data
```

Probably will work for you.

Comment: Not about printing. It should not have included this 2.02152e+17 2021523922099868685 anyways. It should fail the condition (int(%1/10))%10 == 0

Comment: it should include numbers like 205 (i.e. if the second last digit is 0) and not 215 for example.